# Merging object inside an interface in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following in a typing file:

```
interface A {
    anObject: {
        data: string;
    };
    someOtherData: boolean;
}
```

Now I want to change the interface so that **anObject** also includes **data2**. I want the final form to be

```
interface A {
    anObject: {
        data: string;
        data2: string;
    };
    someOtherData: boolean;
}
```

I already tried doing this and it failed:

```
interface A {
    anObject: {
        data2: string;
    }
}
```

Instead of the **anObject** having both data and data2, it only has data2. Is there anyway to keep original keys?

Comment: Can you edit interface A?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmm, how about something like this:

#### orig.ts

```
export interface A {
    anObject: {
        data: string;
    };
    someOtherData: boolean;
}
```

#### extend.ts

```
import {A as _A} from './orig'

interface A extends _A {
  anObject: _A['anObject'] & {
    data2: string;
  }
}
```

That is: rename the original `A` out of the way to `_A` during [import](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import).  Then extend it and merge in the new `data2` property with the original by [intersecting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) it with the [looked-up](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types) `anObject` property.

Or, if you don't mind `A` being a `type` alias and not an `interface`, there's the simpler:

#### extend.ts

```
import {A as _A} from './playground'

type A = _A & {
  anObject: {
    data2: string;
  }
}
```

... in which you still rename the original out of the way, but then simply intersect it with the new part.  Either method gives you the type you want:

```
declare const a: A;
a.anObject.data.charAt(0); // okay
a.anObject.data2.charAt(0); // okay
```

Does that help?